# Passport.js - Chrome will not allow cross-site cookies

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies, passport.js, samesite

My frontend is hosted in (example.com) and backend in (api.example.com). This counts as cross-origin and I'm using Passport.js with Redis for sessions (with cookies). However, this Google Chrome message came up:

Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.

Does this mean that my authentication service will stop working after the Chrome update, and is there any way to come around this? The only solution that comes to my mind right now is hosting the backend on example.com/api. Is there any other way that will not require the backend to change its location?

Comment: `example.com` and `api.example.com` are [cross-_origin_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) but still [same-_site_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Site). Apparently, these are not your _real_ domain names, please tell us the real ones. You may be able to continue your authentication service with [partitioned cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Do you know if this change will affect requests set to sameSite: none and secure: true? I was under the impression this would work, but I am still getting the message when using a setup like OP.

Comment: I would use `Partitioned` only in connection with `SameSite=None; Secure`.